ggplot with shade for the missing months in R?
Update:  Adding uncertainty bounds to the original data.frame that should be part of the plot
I've asked this question before, but I'm asking again to see if there's another method for shading missing months' data without having the lines connected.
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),to = as.Date("2005-12-31"),by = "day"), 
                 Obs = runif(2192, 5,10),
                 Sim = runif(2192, 8,12),
                 Up = runif(2192,13,15),
                 Low = runif(2192,1,4)) %>% 
      filter(between(month(Date),3,10))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Up, ymax = Low), fill = "grey30", alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Obs, col = "blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Sim, col = "red"))

Output needed
This is sort of what I want but without the lines connecting for missing months.

Update 2:  A uncertainty bounds example output


I would probably use the data to find the start and stop times of any periods without consecutive daily measurements:
library(tidyverse)

missing_months <- DF %>% 
  mutate(missing = c(diff(Date), 1) > 1,
         missing = missing | lag(missing)) %>%
  filter(missing) %>%
  mutate(start_stop = rep(c("start", "stop"), length = n())) %>%
  select(Date, start_stop) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = start_stop, values_from = Date, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(start, stop)) %>%
  mutate(start = start + 1, stop = stop - 1)

missing_months
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   start      stop      
#>   <date>     <date>    
#> 1 2000-11-01 2001-02-28
#> 2 2001-11-01 2002-02-28
#> 3 2002-11-01 2003-02-28
#> 4 2003-11-01 2004-02-29
#> 5 2004-11-01 2005-02-28

To stop the lines joining up, you need to label each consecutive run and use this label as a grouping variable in your plot. Remember it's going to be easier to plot with your data pivoted into long format:
DF %>%
  pivot_longer(c('Obs', 'Sim')) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(run = cumsum(c(0, diff(Date) > 1)), group = interaction(name, run)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            data = missing_months, fill = "gray30", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(group = group, x = Date, ymin = Low, ymax = Up), 
              fill = 'gray80') +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = value, color = name, group = group), 
            linewidth = 0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("red3", "blue3", "green4", "black"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = 1))) +
  theme_bw(20)



Thanks @Allan, i just updated my data.frame as i missed on the uncertainty bounds (Up and Low be part of the figure. I tried myself but wasn't successful.

@Hydro so what's the problem? The code just works the same, except you need four colors for the four seties

@Hydro updated to show four colors instead of 2

Hello @Allan, see Update 2 figure to the original question- the uncertainty bounds are not separate lines that would be color coded differently but bounds that would envelope the observation and simulation just the 95%PPU in the Update 2 plot. The Up and Low in my data.frame should be the 95%PPU of Update 2 figure. Hope that make sense.

@Hydro in that case you need to use a geom_ribbon, and not pivot your "up" and "low" columns. See my update.
